# Executing Oracle Function from VB Results in PLS-00221

Tags: vb.net, oracle, plsql

I have a function defined below:

```
 FUNCTION foo (
        param1      IN    VARCHAR2(20)
      , param2      IN    VARCHAR2(255)
      , param3      IN    VARCHAR2(3)
      , param4      IN    VARCHAR2(4)
      , param5      OUT   VARCHAR2(1000)
   )
   RETURN INTEGER IS
   BEGIN
   --Function Code Here
   END foo;
```

That I want to call in my form, I have made the following attempt below:

```
Dim conn As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection()
conn.ConnectionString = DBOraConnectString
Dim cmd As New OracleCommand
Dim param As OracleParameter

cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.CommandText = "foo"

param = New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter
param.ParameterName = "param1"
param.DbType = DbType.AnsiString
param.Value = val1
param.Size = 20
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
cmd.Parameters.Add(param)

param = New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter
param.ParameterName = "param2"
param.DbType = DbType.AnsiString
param.Value = val2
param.Size = 255
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
cmd.Parameters.Add(param)

param = New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter
param.ParameterName = "param3"
param.DbType = DbType.AnsiString
param.Value = val3
param.Size = 3
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
cmd.Parameters.Add(param)

param = New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter
param.ParameterName = "param4"
param.DbType = DbType.AnsiString
param.Value = val4
param.Size = 4
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
cmd.Parameters.Add(param)

param = New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter
param.ParameterName = "param5"
param.DbType = DbType.AnsiString
param.Size = 1000
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
cmd.Parameters.Add(param)

conn.Open()
Try
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Dim vStr As String
    vStr = cmd.Parameters.Item("outVal").Value.ToString
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
conn.Close()
```

Running this results in the following error:

```
ORA-06550: line 1 column 7:
PLS-00221: 'FOO' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: line 1 column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I don't understand why this happens. My connection to the schema is correct and my function compiles and is properly defined so why won't it be executed?

Comment: You need to create another parameter with `param.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`. I think it must be the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your code more compact like this:

```
Dim conn As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection()
conn.ConnectionString = DBOraConnectString
Dim cmd As New OracleCommand

cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.CommandText = "foo"

cmd.Parameters.Add("outVal", ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, OracleDbType.Int32)
cmd.Parameters.Add("param1", ParameterDirection.Input, OracleDbType.Varchar2, 20).Value = val1
cmd.Parameters.Add("param2", ParameterDirection.Input, OracleDbType.Varchar2, 255).Value = val2
cmd.Parameters.Add("param3", ParameterDirection.Input, OracleDbType.Varchar2, 3).Value = val3
cmd.Parameters.Add("param4", ParameterDirection.Input, OracleDbType.Varchar2, 4).Value = val4
cmd.Parameters.Add("param5", ParameterDirection.Output, OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1000)
```

Comment: I want ```param5``` to not have a value.